# How to repeat a function with a for loop

Tags: python, function, loops, opencsv

I open a file and read it with csv and I am trying to move the content to a function so that it can be reused in other programs in this format:

```
my-dic = []
with open('customer.csv','r') as input_file:

    csv_reader = csv.reader(input_file,delimiter = ',')

    for line_number, line in enumerate(csv_reader):
    
        if line_number == 0: # skip the header
       
            continue
   
    
        def customer_file(): 
    
            my_dic.append({
        
                'First Name':line[1],
                'Last name':line[2],
                'Age(Years)':int(line[3]),
       })
customer_file()
```

the csv files has 100 rows and ! am expecting the dictionary to be created for all the rows.On calling the function only the last row of the file is created . I read that this is late binding and that I have to force early binding by using default argument in the function. I passed line_number = 1, as parameter in the function so that it will start from line_number 1 of the csv file, this does not work too

How can I implement this so that when I call the function, the dictionary created will contain all the rows of the csv file not the last row only

Comment: Do you have an example of your csv? That would prove useful to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Defining a function in a loop and then only calling it at the end, is not how you call a function in a loop. And `my-dic` is not a valid variable name.

Comment: my-dic was a typo. I intended my_dic. Anyway, how can I implement calling the function so that the function is repeated the number of times the loop is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to simplify your problem you can make use of list comprehension to obtain your required solution by using `next(csv_reader)` in order to skip the first iteration of the loop.

```
import csv

with open('customer.csv','r') as input_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(input_file,delimiter = ',')
    next(csv_reader) # Skip header
    my_dic = [{"First Name": line[0], "Last Name": line[1], "Age(Years)": int(line[2])} for line in csv_reader]

print(my_dic)
```

I will also provide a similar solution to what you provided as I cannot assume your knowledge with the Python language. The use of a function will not really be needed to append to your `my_dic` dictionary, so I have eliminated that. You may need to adjust the indices where your data is situated as I am working of sample data I created.

```
import csv

my_dic = []
with open('customer.csv','r') as input_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(input_file,delimiter = ',')
    next(csv_reader) # Skip header

    for n, line in enumerate(csv_reader):
        print(line)
        my_dic.append({
            'First Name':line[0],
            'Last name':line[1],
            'Age(Years)':int(line[2]),
        })

print(my_dic)
```

UPDATE as per comment

```
import csv

def dic_append(line):
    my_dic.append({"First Name": line[0], "Last Name": line[1], "Age(Years)": int(line[2])})

my_dic = []
with open('customer.csv','r') as input_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter = ',')
    next(csv_reader) # Skip header
    for line in csv_reader:
        dic_append(line)

print(my_dic)
```

Comment: Yes. I know i can do this directly without the function . But, there are several place in the code where the dictionary will be needed and i cant just be reading my file and creating a new dictionary each time the dictionary is needed . So, i thought of passing the line of code that involves the dictionary to a function so that when it is called , we can have the dictionary of the details without a need to read a file again

Comment: See updated to better suit your need. As explained.

Comment: Yes . The updated version works with little adjustment on my csv file . I was actually mixing up process of calling a function